# How to read messages from Google Group

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-groups

I'm trying to make a script to read all the messages from a Google Group and count how many from specific label there are. I have a collaborative inbox to manage issues and I would like to build reports with this information.

I have checked Group and GroupsApp classes, and they don't allow to access messages, they only give you global information from the group (email, users, roles...).

I tried to use GmailApp, but I can only retrieve my own messages (I usually delete group messages from my inbox).

Could be possible to access the group messages?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, there is currently no API or method to retrieve messages from a Google Group. You may need to [use a shared mailbox](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350?hl=en) instead of a Google Group if you need programatic access to the mail data.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive copies in your personal inbox, dont delete them manually, instead use a gmail filter to label them and use a script to process that label and delete them once processed.